# Error when using YUI3: "Y.QueryString.parse is not a function"

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I'm building a Squarespace page, and I want to have an outgoing link on the page whose query parameters are set according to query parameters on the page itself. Since Squarespace embeds YUI3 in every site automatically, I'm trying to use that (even though I have more experience with jquery).

Example: The page is loaded as `http://example.com/page/?email=foo@bar.com`. I have a link on the page that goes to `http://another.example.com/page` which should be modified to go to `http://another.example.com/page?address=foo@bar.com`.

The following code does exactly what I need when I paste it in the browser console:

```
var MyButton = Y.all('a[href="http://another.example.com/page"]');
var QueryString = Y.QueryString.parse(window.location.search.substring(1));
MyButton.setAttribute('href','http://another.example.com/page?address=' + QueryString.email);
```

However, when I put that code in the page source, then when the page loads, the following error appears in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Y.QueryString.parse is not a function`

My current theory is that YUI3 loads asynchronously in pieces, and this code runs at a point when Y.all is available but Y.QueryString.parse is not... is that right? What would be the best solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yui3 is indeed built around asychonous modules loading, in this case you miss the `querystring` module.

You need to wrap your code with a Y.use call:

```
Y.use('querystring', function(Y) {
  var MyButton = Y.all('a[href="http://another.example.com/page"]');
  var QueryString = Y.QueryString.parse(window.location.search.substring(1));
  MyButton.setAttribute('href', 'http://another.example.com/page?address=' + QueryString.email);
});
```